# Expected Value of 2 jointly distributed random variables

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the covariance of (X,Y).

I know that Y|X~Bin(n,x) and X~U(0,1). I've also found the expected value of Y, but do not know how to find the expected value of XY (which is used in the formula for covariance).

Where do I go from here? I feel like I'm missing a crucial piece of information relating E(XY) to E(Y|X).

Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the crucial piece is that E(XY) = E(X E(Y |X) ) ;)